# Bordermatrix from $ \mathrm\LaTeX $

Tags: matrix, latex

How would I create an output similar to the result produced by this $ \mathrm\LaTeX $ code:

```
M = \bordermatrix{~ & x & y \cr
                  A & 1 & 0 \cr
                  B & 0 & 1 \cr}
```

which when compiled, looks like

[image: Complied bordermatrix]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to work, at least for your example:

```
TraditionalForm @ Grid[{{Null, Grid[{{x, y}}]}, {TableForm@{{A}, {B}}, 
  MatrixForm[IdentityMatrix[2]]}}]
```

[image]

You can make a little function that generalises it:

```
makeBordermatrix[mat_?MatrixQ, top_?VectorQ, side_?VectorQ] := 
 TraditionalForm@
  Grid[{{Null, Grid[{top}]}, {TableForm[Transpose@{side}], 
     MatrixForm[mat]}}]
```

So we have:

```
makeBordermatrix[IdentityMatrix[3], {x, y, z}, {A, B, C}]
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, welcolme to Mathematica.SE James!

Comment: Ah nice, I didn't quite manage to get `TraditionalForm` to give it this way

Comment: This isn't very robust, though: try `makeBordermatrix[IdentityMatrix[3] {aaaaaaaaaa, 0, 0}, {x, y, z}, {A, B, C}]` and the columns get misaligned. To fix this, you could make each element of the top row have an `Overlay` in which all matrix entries below it are stacked on top of each other with `Opacity[0]`, to force the top row to accomodate the maximum width of the row.

Comment: @Jens I know, I didn't enforce matching dimensions or lengths of objects (limited lunch break time), but it would be straightforward to do.